# Comparing contents of all files in a directory C

Tags: c, arrays

I need to make program that compare content of all files in directory and detects duplicates. Program works fine until it starts comparing files inside the `for` loop. I think there might be error in array but I can't find any. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int listFiles(char *path, int a, char ***array);

int main() {
    char path[100];
    char **array = NULL;
    int a = 0;
    printf("Enter path to list files: ");
    scanf("%s", path);
    listFiles(path, a, &array);
    return 0;
}

int listFiles(char *basePath, int a, char ***array) {
    char path[1000], c, *d = NULL;
    FILE *input_file;
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);
    if (!dir) {
        return 1;
    }
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "\\");
            strcat(path, dp->d_name);
            input_file = fopen(path, "r");
            if (input_file == NULL) {
                fclose(input_file);
            }
            if (input_file) {
                printf("%s\n", path);
                while ((c = getc(input_file)) != EOF)
                    d = realloc(d, (x + 1) * sizeof(*d));
                (d)[x++] = c;
            }
            *array = realloc(*array, (a + 1) * sizeof(**array));
            (*array)[a++] = d;
            if (a > 1) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a - 1; ++j) {
                    if (!memcmp(array[a], array[j], 999)) {
                        printf("duplikat\n");
                        free(array[a]);
                        --a;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        listFiles(path, a, array);
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Protip: hash files individually, then only compare files with matching hashes.

Comment: What @Dai said. There is no merit in doing it any other way. You also might want to google the term Three-Star-Programmer. Also, your `array` is no array.

Comment: I see some linux specific functions, so you probably have access to md5sum. This might be easier as a shell script.

Comment: An array of struct (e.g. `struct cmpinfo { char *name; uint8_t *hash; }` will do. (but I agree, that a simple shell script, and if using bash, an associative array, of filenames and hashes would be a much simpler solution)

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((c = getc(input_file)) != EOF)
d=realloc(d, (x+1)*sizeof(*d));
(d)[x++] = c;
```

Is equal to:

```
while ((c = getc(input_file)) != EOF) {
   d = realloc(d, (x+1)*sizeof(*d));
}
(d)[x++] = c;
```

Which reads from a file until EOF and reallocates a `d` pointer with the same size for each character in the file. Then is assigns to the last element in `d` the value of EOF. So the content of the file is not saved in `d` pointer.

1. Always explicitly use `{` and `}` (except for cases when don't).
2. Check for overflow.

   ```
   size_t pathsize = sizeof(path);
   assert(pathsize > strlen(basePath) + 1 + strlen(dp->d_name) + 1);
   strcpy(path, basePath);
   strcat(path, "\\");
   strcat(path, dp->d_name);
   ```

   Do similar checks everytime you do something dangerous.
3. What's the point of closing NULL file?

   ```
       if(input_file == NULL){
           fclose(input_file);
       }
       if (input_file){
   ```
4. The number `999` is very magical.

   ```
   memcmp(array[a],array[j],999)
   ```
5. You incorrectly handle arrays. Or don't free memory. I don't know.

   ```
   *array = realloc(*array, (a+1)*sizeof(**array));
   (*array)[a++] = d;
   ...
   free(array[a]);
   ```
6. There is a little point in `char ***` variable. Don't use `***` (unless in cases where you use them). The `char***array` can be completely removed.
7. Start with a good abstraction. First write a function that will compare two files `bool files_compare(const char *file1, const char *file2);`. Then write a function that will list all files in a directory. Then for each pair of files listed compare them. There is a little need to no need in storing the content of the file in dynamic memory (what if you have files that have 10Gb and a system with 1Gb of memory?).
8. The `listFiles` function is untimately is endlessly recursively calling itself if there is at least one file in the directory.

   ```
   int listFiles(char *basePath, int a, char ***array)
   {
       ...
       DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);
       ...
       while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
          ...
          listFiles(path,a,array);
     }
   }
   ```
9. This code has many errors. It reuses old memory, incorrectly handles arrays, has some strange magic numbers, leaks memory, does not close opened files, is not protected against overflow, and opens the directory recursively.

Comment: Refering Kamil's point #3: you probably want to return if the file can't be opened, since there's nothing you can do then anyway.  Also, if all you're trying to do is compare files and list their names, consider looking into shell (ksh/bash) scripting, as your goal as I understand it is about a 10-line shell script.